# Burned binary files don't match original files

Tags: data-cd, burning

Kernel = 2.6.23.1-42
genisoimage 1.1.6 (Linux)
Wodim 1.1.10

```
Create iso image:
genisoimage -V "Data_Layer_1" -v -J -r -o cdl_data_1.iso cdl_1/

Test integrity of iso image:
mount -t iso9660 -o loop cdl_data_1.iso /mnt/iso_test/
cksum each of 6 files in iso image against original file, byte counts and CRCs match
umount /mnt/iso_test/

Burn iso to CD-R:
Close X11 desktop, go to single user console mode as root user
insert blank disk
mount -l, check that blank disk isn't mounted 
wodim -v -dao speed=2 dev=/dev/cdrw cdl_data_1.iso
eject disk

Look for burn errors:
no errors or warnings in wodim output
dmesg | tail
cdrom: This disk doesn't have any tracks I recognize! 
tail /var/log/messages
localhost kernel: cdrom: This disk doesn't have any tracks I recognize! (The timestamp matches the time the blank disk was inserted)

Test individual burned files:
startx
insert burned CD
execute cksum on individual files on mounted CD, byte counts do not match, CRC values match 
example of post-burn cksum comparison
   [kfw@localhost ~]$ cksum /media/Data_Layer_1/CDL_2012_004.zip 
   1556659744 97975264 /media/Data_Layer_1/CDL_2012_004.zip
   [kfw@localhost ~]$ cksum CDL_2012_004.zip 
   752249099 97975264 CDL_2012_004.zip

example of cmp execution on individual files
    [kfw@localhost ~]$ cmp /media/Data_Layer_1/CDL_2012_004.zip CDL_2012_004.zip 
    /media/Data_Layer_1/CDL_2012_004.zip CDL_2012_004.zip differ: byte 705623, line 1199

copy individual files from burned CD to HDD, test integrity
unzip CDL_2012_004.zip
...     
   error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
   bad CRC 27b7a348  (should be eb348979)
```

All data CD burns of different types of binary files suffer this problem; I have burned many dozens of audio disks with no problems at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"byte counts do not match, CRC values match..."* You have it backward.  The CRC is first.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have bad hardware. Its probably low-quality or defectively manufactured CD-R blanks, but it could also be a bad drive (either the reading drive or the writing drive, if those are different).

You're not noticing it with the audio disks (I assume you mean CD-DA, as in the discs you put in an ordinary CD player) because the players are designed to detect and hide slight corruptions in the audio track. If you re-ripped the discs, and compared to your original audio, you'd find errors.

On the other hand, compressed files are *extremely* sensitive to corruption, so you notice those.

I'd start by buying a new blank, from a different company (or at least production batch). A while ago Taiyo Yuden blanks were considered the best, but I'm not sure if they still are.

Comment: Thank you for your response derobert. The write device is a PLEXTOR 716A, firmware v1.07. The PLEXTOR drive is also used to read/play, and I play the audio disks on a Sony combination CD-DVD player as well as in my car. I am using CD-R media, Memorex/Ritek. I rip the "masters" using cdparanoia and burn the copies using wodim. I'll try ripping an entire disk (using dd?) and compare to the original to see what that yields. Your suggestion about testing alternate media resonates, I have read postings about the Memorex disks being suspect.

Comment: http://www.cdmediaworld.com/hardware/cdrom/cd_quality.shtml and http://www.digitalfaq.com/reviews/dvd-media.htm have some reviews of blank media manufacturers. Take them with several grains of salt.

Comment: New blanks or a new burner, @user56408. Or cleaning the one you have.

Comment: * Upgrade Media - No change  * Clean laser inside optical drive ala [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaiTJYHQCCg) - No change  * Replace drive unit - SOLVED  It looks like the drive was faulty.  Thanks to all that responded.